# Setting the windows Explorer Default View

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Is there a way to set the default location of the windows explorer window when you open it?

For example whenever i open windows explorer i want it to open on the 'My Documents' folder.

I'm using Win7 Home Prem 32-bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this: [How to Change Windows Explorer startup folder.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17415/set-the-windows-explorer-startup-folder-in-windows-7/)

So in your case, you need to define

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /N,::{450D8FBA-AD25-11D0-98A8-0800361B1103}
```

as Target.

[image]